# Share webstorm and intellij settings

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

We are sharing our Project settings inside our team (.idea folder is committed to git) and some of us are using IntelliJ IDEA, some are using WebStorm.

What is really annoying is that WebStorm removes the IntelliJ IDEA settings. For example in misc.xml IntelliJ IDEA adds the following:

`<component name="ProjectRootManager" version="2" assert-keyword="false" jdk-15="false" />`

This is removed by WebStorm and then added again by IntelliJ IDEA. So in almost every commit this is toggled.

Is there any way to work around this except for completely ignoring the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different Idea-based IDEs (RubyMine, PHPStorm, WebStorm, PyCharm, IDEA) have the same project format (`.idea`) but different settings/module types that aren't compatible. So sharing .idea folder may results in losing your settings, etc.
If you like to work on the same sources in different IDEs, I'd suggest sharing the sources folder(s) but keeping the `.idea` folders separated.

Related feature request: [IDEA-140809](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-140809)